# Pass Record Selection Data to Subreport

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport

I have a main report that uses a formula in the Record Selection. The numbers are set by choosing the "is between" option in the Select Expert. I need these numbers to go through to the subreport, however, no matter what I do, I can't get both numbers through to the subreport, just the one. Is there any way I can pass both these numbers through to the subrport? Neither of them are based on parameters, we use a system here at work where the parameter is set at runtime.

Attached is a picture of the main reports' Select Expert - I need to get the 2 and 6 through to the subreport. Is this possible?

Thank you.
[image: Select Expert in Main Report with the two numbers I want to pass to subreport]

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the link below seems to work, if you have a similar problem. To quote:

> Create two formulas
>
> MinValue as Minimum({vw_P_SDL_MTDSummaryList.PAYROLLDETAIL_ID})
>   and MaxValue as Maximum({vw_P_SDL_MTDSummaryList.PAYROLLDETAIL_ID})
>
> and pass them to the subreport as a parameter without linking it to any of the > field in sub report.

http://scn.sap.com/message/16971134#16971134